# initializationError with Eclipse and JUNIT4 when executing a single test

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4, eclipse-indigo

My test class is this one:

```
    /**
     * The Class TestAddSubscriber.
     */
    @RunWith(LabelledParameterized.class)
    public class TestAddSubscriber extends AbstractTestSubscriber {

        /**
         * Instantiates a new test add subscriber.
         * 
         * @param label
         *            the label
         * @param apiKey
         *            the api key
         * @param userKey
         *            the user key
         * @param customerId
         *            the customer id
         */
        public TestAddSubscriber(String label, String apiKey, String userKey,
                int customerId) {
            super(label, apiKey, userKey, customerId);
        }

        /**
         * @see com.contactlab.api.test.AbstractTest#setUp()
         */
        @Override
        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            super.setUp();
        }

        /**
         * @see com.contactlab.api.test.AbstractTest#tearDown()
         */
        @Override
        @After
        public void tearDown() throws Exception {
            super.tearDown();
        }

        /**
         * Generated data.
         * 
         * @return the collection
         */
        @Parameters
        public static Collection<Object[]> generatedData() {
            return DataProvider.generatedCorrectSubscriberData();
        }

        /**
         * Test add subscriber with internal pk id case sensitive.
         * 
         * @outcome: success
         * @expected: success
         * @obtained: success
         */
        @Test
        public void testAddSubscriberWithInternalPkIdCaseSensitive() {

  /** this is the test **/

        }

    /**
    * other tests
    **/
    }
```

If I execute the Test Suite I'm not having problem but If highlight only one of them and run it  I'm having `Unrooted Tests -> InitializationError`

The class uses `Parameterized`.

The exception is:

```
TestAddSubscriber.testAddSubscriberWithInternalPkIdCaseSensitive
Unrooted Tests
initializationError(org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter)
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching Method testAddSubscriberWithInternalPkIdCaseSensitive(com.contactlab.api.test.subscriber.TestAddSubscriber) from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@18872380
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestMethodReference.<init>(JUnit4TestMethodReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It works as expected (you can right-click+run individual tests) in Juno, using JUnit 4.11 and @RunWith(Parameterized.class). Versioning is quite off though from your setup... :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can possibly workaround the problem by overriding the org.junit.runners.ParentRunner#filter by extending the Parameterized

```java
public class IDECompatibleParameterized extends Parameterized {

    public void filter(Filter filter) throws NoTestsRemainException {
        super.filter(new FilterDecorator(filter));
    }

   /**
     * Running single test in case of parameterized test causes issue as explained in
     * http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65966
     *
     * As a workaround we wrap the original filter and then pass it a wrapped description
     * which removes the parameter part (See deparametrizedName)
     */
    private static class FilterDecorator extends Filter {
        private final Filter delegate;

        private FilterDecorator(Filter delegate) {
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldRun(Description description) {
            return delegate.shouldRun(wrap(description));
        }

        @Override
        public String describe() {
            return delegate.describe();
        }
    }

    private static Description wrap(Description description) {
        String name = description.getDisplayName();
        String fixedName = deparametrizedName(name);
        Description clonedDescription =
                Description.createSuiteDescription(fixedName,description.getAnnotations().toArray(new Annotation[0]));
        for(Description child : description.getChildren()){
            clonedDescription.addChild(wrap(child));
        }
        return clonedDescription;
    }

    private static String deparametrizedName(String name) {
        //Each parameter is named as [0], [1] etc
        if(name.startsWith("[")){
            return name;
        }

        //Convert methodName[index](className) to
        //methodName(className)
        int indexOfOpenBracket = name.indexOf('[');
        int indexOfCloseBracket = name.indexOf(']')+1;
        return name.substring(0,indexOfOpenBracket).concat(name.substring(indexOfCloseBracket));
    }
}
```

Another way would be to change the method name in Launch configuration to have the parameter name like `testAddSubscriberWithInternalPkIdCaseSensitive[0]`